# Looking for a solution to discover common text patterns in multiple strings

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a solution where I can examine thousands of strings that share some similarity and have it discover appropriate regex pattern(s) that will give a 100% match on all strings?

The catch is that I need to process about 10 categories of thousands of strings, so I need to repeat this discovering for all categories -- and of course -- the patterns for category A can't have matches in category B.

Comment: The software you want does not exist.  Even if it did the regular expression would be horrible and could never match a string 100% of the time.

Comment: There probably is software which attempts to do this, but I agree that such a thing would probably not produce meaningful results most of the time. [This page](http://www.regexmagic.com/autogenerate.html) makes the same argument.